# Where are temporary (rvalue) stored?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int n, i, j, max1 = -1000000000, max2 = -1000000000;
    cin >> n;
    long long int a[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i] > max1)
            max1 = a[i];
        j = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > max2 && i != j)
            max2 = a[i];
    }
    cout << max1*max2;
}
```

Suppose `max1=3`,`max2=6`
then the last line of the program outputs '18`on terminal ; we have not used any variable to store the result of this multiplication operation ,then where is '18` stored before being printed on screen. Is a new variable created by the compiler at compile time to store this value?

Comment: VLA's arent standard c++.

Comment: usually you need to post code that is compilable and allow us to reproduce the issue....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<<` is an operator for `cout`. Operators are just like function, they takes parameters. So What happens is that `max1*max2` is computed and passed as parameter to this guy: `ostream& operator<< (long long val);` Details on how that value is stored depends highly on how the compiler decides to optimize that specific call to `operator<<` for `cout`, but you can think it is stored on the stack somewhere at some point.

That said, `max1*max2` is a temporary (an rvalue). It's up to the compiler where to store a temporary; the standard only specifies its lifetime. Typically, it will be treated as an automatic variable, stored in registers or in the function's stack frame, but again it's up to the compiler.

Think about what happens when you call something like the following:

```
int n=13;
int nn= sqrt(n*(n+1)*-n+5));
```

The value for `n*(n+1)*-n+5)` is first computed and passed as parameter to `sqrt`.
The same thing is happening in `cout<<max1max2`

---

**VLA** are not part of the standard in `C++` even if they are supported by means of an extension by both `g++` and `clang++`. Consider using a container instead. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).